# PutAsJsonAsync does not work when dto has data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm seeing some strange behavior with HttpClient and Web API with my DTOs. When I have data annotations in place for my properties, HttpClient.PutAsJsonAsync() does not work. I can't receive anything at the Web API end. Some code to explain:

My MVC 4 web page calls the Web API with this code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri+"/"+MyObject.Id, MyObject).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Returns 500 when i use MyObject with annotations                             
}
```

Web API controller code to receive. Note that this is not even trigged when MyObject has annotations:

```
public MyObject Put(MyObject myObject)
{
        try
        {
            if (myObject == null) throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }
}
```

MyObject DTO when it works:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AuditProgramId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
 }
```

MyObject DTO when it doesn't work:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AuditProgramId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

It works with these values without annotations, but fails with annotations:

```
var myObj = new MyObject {
    Id=4,
    Title="Test Title",
    StartDate=DateTime.Today,
    EndDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)
};
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of an object that fails? `new MyObject { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro your scenario, and the exception message actually provide a solution to this problem:

`Property 'StartDate' on type 'MvcApplication.Model.MyObject' is invalid. Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].`

I have modified my `MyObject` class accordingly and I got your scenario to work.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> AuditProgramId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

FYI, a bug relating to this scenario is recently fixed to make things simpler:  [Overly aggressive validation for applying [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to required properties with value types](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/270)